# error putting paths in the function () in python

Tags: python

im trying to run this code but I have an error when I put the path in the function the path turns grey and I have a red line under it, maybe someone can help me with that?

```
import shutil
from pathlib import Path
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET


def contains_drone(path):
 tree = ET.parse(path.as_posix())
 root = tree.getroot()
 for obj in root.findall('object'):
    rank = obj.find('name').text
    if rank == 'car':           
         return True
return False


def move_drone_files(src="D:\\TomProject\\Images\\", 
dst="D:\\TomProject\\Done"):
         
src, dst = Path(src), Path(dst)
for path in src.iterdir():
   if path.suffix == '.xml' and contains_drone(path):
       print(f'Moving {path.as_posix()} to {dst.as_posix()}')
       shutil.move(path, dst)

if __name__ == "__main__":
 move_drone_files()
```

Comment: please provide the code with perfect indentation and more info so i can figure out what's going wrong

Comment: In a function definition, you don't directly use the correct path. Otherwise, parameters would not be necessary. Instead, uese variable names and then call the function using the explicit path. If you wanted to provide a default path, use variable_name=default_value.

Comment: You never create variables `src`, `dst` before you use them

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the paths you define are your src and dst paths, your function definition should look like this, with corrected indentation and function definition:

```
def move_drone_files(src, dst):
    src, dst = Path(src), Path(dst)
    for path in src.iterdir():
       if path.suffix == '.xml' and contains_drone(path):
           print(f'Moving {path.as_posix()} to {dst.as_posix()}')
           shutil.move(path, dst)
```

And in your program you call the function like this:

```
move_drone_files('D:\\TomProject\\Images', 'D:\\TomProject\\Images\\Done') 
#or 
move_drone_files(src='D:\\TomProject\\Images', dst='D:\\TomProject\\Images\\Done')
```

Or if you want to use the paths as the default arguments for the function, you should start the definition of the function like this:

```
def move_drone_files(src='D:\\TomProject\\Images', dst='D:\\TomProject\\Images\\Done'):
```

Check python docs (choose correct python version) of function definition and default argument values for more info: https://docs.python.org/3.10/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions

Comment: now it looks just fine but somehow the code does nothing and i have no errors, when i run it it just goes: press any key to continue

Comment: Hard to say what is wrong, without seeing the source code of the program itself.

Comment: what do you mean by source code, im pretty new to python. this is the only code i run

Comment: What you have posted above are function definitions. Functions are only executed if they are called in the program.  The behavior you are describing sounds like something the program itself is doing e.g. asking a user input. Maybe this resource will help you: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp

Comment: yes im trying to make this program work like this without source code, only with user input

Comment: As I understood, your issue is still that the functions you have defined are not executing. So to help you further, it would be useful to have you post the part where you are trying to call these functions, probably where you call the input() function.

Comment: sorry for the question, I dont understand what do you mean by calling the function. how i can call it?

Comment: Please read the contents of the link I posted before (https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp). It will explain functions and function calls.

Comment: You may want to use raw strings for the paths

Comment: I have another question in this line:  if path.suffix == '.xml' and contains_drone(path):. can i add there also .jpeg and .txt so it will move the same name files with the different extensions?

Comment: Sure, you just need to create another condition under the for loop "for path in src.iterdir()". e.g. elif path.suffix == ".jpeg": . You cannot add it to the same if condition that you already have because the condition "and contains_drone(path)" would probably fail. You should probably read more about if ... else statements: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_conditions.asp